# Checking if object is null and access members in the same if

Tags: c#

I am refractoring a line of code from .NET 4.0 to 3.5, the actual code is

```
if(bar?.foo == "outdated")
    bar = new Bar();
```

Can i refractor these lines in this way and retain the same logic?

```
if(bar == null || bar.foo == "outdated")
    bar = new Bar();
```

Does the `if` evaluation stop after the the `bar == null` (since the expression would be true, no matter whether the other part returns true or false) or does it continue to check `bar.foo` even if the first part already returned true, and therefore throw a null exception?

Comment: Offtopic: why are you going to a lower version on .NET? (just interest)

Comment: Could have been answered with a look at the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx

Comment: The answer is **yes**,  the if evaluation stops after the the bar == null .
That's the difference between `|` and `||` , while `|` will continue compiling even when the first section of the condition returns true. 
check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx) out for more information.

Comment: @RvdK i was creating a plug-in for our software, but it lately turned out that this plug-in was also required for an older version

Comment: @Null you are right, i edited the example to better reflect what i'm actually doing (Same for Hans Kesting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it stops, it is called short circuit logic,
Check this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx